# NGINX Proxy Pass multiple folders

Tags: nginx

I have a NGINX proxy and I want to redirect different folders to different web servers. The issue is that the local servers are looking for absolute paths for images, JS, APIs etc.
How can I make it so there is a rewrite rule or something like it to mitigate the issue?

Below is what I currently have for the server config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sample.com;

    root /var/www/html;


    location / {
        return 403;

    }

    location /path/ch2 {
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.1.50:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_buffering off;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vauge to answer.

Comment: Please provide request examples.

Comment: The local Servers HTML is referencing the assets, for example the js file using an absolute path as so:
<script src="/path/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
since the proxy 'location' is not served on the root, then it is not able to load the js files etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing is to use the sub_filter

sub_filter "/path/" "/ch2/path/";
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript;